# restDocs requestParameters cannot find

Tags: spring-data-jpa, junit4, spring-restdocs

```
import static org.springframework.restdocs.request.RequestDocumentation.requestParameters;


User
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   static requestParameters
  location: class org.springframework.restdocs.request.RequestDocumentation
```

I want to use requestParameters for test, but cannot find

so I tried this below ways, but can't resolve it

please help me.....

Double-check that the `spring-restdocs-mockmvc` dependency has been added correctly to your project's `build.gradle file or pom.xml file`.
To verify that your project successfully downloaded the spring-restdocs-mockmvc dependency, try clearing your Gradle or Maven cache and forcing the dependency to be downloaded again.

To refresh a Gradle or Maven project:

Refresh your Gradle or Maven project in your IDE to ensure it reflects the latest changes. In IntelliJ IDEA, click the "Refresh" button in the Gradle tab on the right, or in Eclipse,

Right-click the project and select "Maven" > "Update Project".

To restart the IDE:

Sometimes the IDE may not accurately reflect the latest dependency information. Restart your IDE to see if this resolves the issue.
Using the correct Spring REST Docs version:

Make sure the version of Spring REST Docs you are using is up to date. You also need to check whether it is compatible with the version of Spring Boot you are using. If you use incompatible versions, unexpected problems may occur.

Comment: What version of Spring REST Docs are you using? In 3.0, support for request parameters was removed and replaced by support for documenting query parameters and form parameters separately.

Comment: I checked restDocs version and It's 3.01 ver. Very thank you. :)